# How did Joshua locate his sons bodies at Gallipoli?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-water-diviner

We see in the **The Water Diviner** that **Joshua** has set out to find his sons that went to WW1 (Arthur and the other two I can't remember their names). After his wife **Lizzy** commits suicide, he promises her by praying that he will find his sons and maybe if they are alive, to bring them home.

But when Joshua finally gets to **Gallipoli** via boat, after a while he has visions that I don't know how he even started seeing them, but he finds himself in a ditch, walks in circles and all of a sudden he is standing right on top of his sons temprary grave of where they died.

**How does he find them and why**?